# Where does vscode extensions store login information?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a few extensions where I have logged in to an online service like Azure Account and Docker Hub.

Each time I start VSCode, I am able to use these services, which is great.

But, how is this login-info stored? Will I have to go through each of them and logout, or are there some settings etc. that I can delete, to make sure I am logged out of everything?

What if I delete extensions? Is the login-info still there, so that if the extension is re-installed, it will be immediately logged in?

Comment: Are you sure VSCode stores the login information? If it were me I would assume the extension does.

Comment: Extensions that are wrappers for command-line programs are very likely to not care at all about auth and just let it to the underlying software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing this information is up to each extension.

Many of the Azure ones use [this extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-account) so that account info can be shared among extensions. Behind the scenes, I believe it uses the system keychain/keyvault through [keytar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar)

The [docker extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker) also uses keytar but has its own account management functionality in VS Code for logging in and logging out.

For extensions that manage creds in general, you must log out of each extension. The exception would be for a shared account (like with the Azure extensions) where you would only have to log the account out once.

Comment: It would make sense that I'd have to log out of each.
I was just thinking maybe there's a way of removing this info in one swoop.
If e.g. I use VS Code on some other machine (we have Jenkins nodes running that automatically logs into windows so UI tests can run), and if I use VSCode on that, I'd like to make sure I'm not signed in to some service or other, that I have forgotten about.

Comment: VS code now [supports](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SecretStorage) it internally. The docker extension mentioned here has [migrated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2699) to that. You don't need keytar anymore.